# How Entity Framework 4 domain mapping work exactly?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I know Linq to SQL work such as setting META attributes around your model. What i am looking to do is building my model then setting this model to work with EF 4.

Are the same approach working with EF 4 ?

Is this called the Code-First approach or its totally something else ?

Ive done some research but i can't seem to figure out how exactly to map a domain to work with EF 4. This include keys/relations integrity.

I would love to see a simple code example with some explanations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model-first development allows you to build the model in the designer, then generate the database based on that model.  Code-first allows  you to generate the database based on your code, or use the code to work with an existing database too.

Both those options are viable; for code-first, V5 has a lot of improvements you will want to look out for.

HTH.

Comment: It is okay to use the V5 in a production environnement ?

Comment: It's almost ready (deployed Q1 2011), I think in CTP currently.  You'd have to read whether its allowed to be deployed to production.  It may be OK, but there's no support and if you find a bug, it's pretty much "wait until MS releases the next version" to fix it...